# Animated Views move outside of my layout

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` which contains several `RelativeLayouts` and `LinearLayouts` like this:

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

      <RelativeLayout >

      </RelativeLayout>

      <LinearLayout >

      </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Now, when I click on one of those layouts, I want it to expand and reveal more information. I have managed to do this by scaling the layout I want vertically with a `PropertyAnimator`:

```
relativeLayout.animate().scaleY(100).setDuration(duration).start();
```

At the same time, I use another `PropertyAnimator` to move  any `Views` below the one I expanded vertically so that there's enough space for the expanded layout. So far it is working.

Unfortunately, the `Views` that move somehow end up outside of the viewport of the `ScrollView`, so I'm unable to scroll down and see the information in those `Views`. Essentially, the vertical translation of those views renders their lower part unreachable, since the viewport does not expand too.

I have set `android:fillViewPort="true"` on the `ScrollView`. And I have also tried to do it programmatically with `setFillViewPort()` but neither has had any effect.

What's wrong? Why is it not working?

Comment: You are trying to solve this problem the wrong way. You have to do it the other way around. The steps are: Register an `OnPreDrawListener` and record the current size and position of all views in your `ScrollView`, then resize your the views in the `ScrollView`. The `OnPreDrawListener` will be called once the next frame is ready to be drawn, which in this case will be after the layouting process initiated by the resizing has finished. In the `OnPreDrawListener` you record the new heights and positions of all views in the `ScrollView`, but you return false so the new state will not be drawn.

Comment: Now you have both the old and new Heights and positions of all views and you can start your animation. The most important part is that you remove the `OnPreDrawListener` immediately in the callback. You only want to catch that one callback caused by the resizing of your views.

Comment: So to summarize: You resize your views and let android preform one layouting process which correctly resizes and repositions all views on your layout. You prevent this new state from being drawn by returning false in the `OnPreDrawListener` and then animate the views from their old to their new positions while at the same time animating want changes in height/width. The trick is that android calculates all values for you and while you are performing your animations all views will already be correctly resized and repositioned in your layout.

Comment: In a sense you let android do the heavy lifting for you and you just have to record the before and after values and then perform the animation.

Comment: Xaver, I have been looking for an opportunity to use a ViewTreeObserver / onPreDrawListener for quite some time since it's a skill I'm sorely lacking in. Thanks for the VERY detailed answer, I'll use the rest of the day happily working the implementation!

Comment: I am glad I could help! I will write this up with maybe an example or two later once I am home and in front of my computer. Until then feel free to ask me anything in the comment section here.

Comment: Xaver, it seems like I'm having the same trouble with the ScrollView's content going off the viewport. Of course, I can't be sure that my kindergarten-like implementation of the ViewTreeObserver class is not at fault! I suppose that if the OnPreDrawListener worked correctly, the problem would be solved, am I right?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, something important came up, anyway check out my answer for a detailed explanation of how to perform such animations. But you should first try if `LayoutTransition`s suit your needs. They take care of a lot of animation work for you like adding/removing/resizing/moving `View`s. See my answer for a quick explanation of how to use them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you perform translation animations on `Views` then those `Views` don't really move inside the layout. Its just visual for the User, but when it comes to layouting and/or measuring than any translation values are ignored. It is always as if the `Views` are not translated at all.

What I am guessing you are doing right now is this:

- You react to the click event and expand the `View` you want to expand.
- You calculate how much the other Views need to move to accommodate the expanded `View`.
- Then you perform translate animations on those `Views` by much they need to move.
- And then as a result suddenly a few `Views` move off screen.

This approach can actually never work. You always need to remember that a `Views` position in the layout is determined **just** by the layout. All your translations are essentially just for show. So this is what's actually happening when you try to do the above:

- You react the to the click event and expand the `View`.
- This expansion causes Android to start a layouting and measuring process. The positions and sizes of all Views is calculated and they are positioned at their new location with their new size.
- Since now the `Views` are already at the location they are going to be after the expansion you translation animation just moves the `Views` further down, beyond the point they are supposed  to be.
- As a side effect of this the `Views` seem to move off screen for no apparent reason.

So what can you do about this? Essentially you need to tackle this problem the other way around. As I mentioned above Android already calculates the new sizes and positions of all `Views` for you, and you can use that to your advantage.

There are two basic solutions for your problem. Either you let Android perform the animations for you with `LayoutTransitions` or you perform your animations manually. Both ways use something called the `ViewTreeObserver`. It can be used to listen for changes in the layout or new drawing processes.

But first and foremost: `ScrollView` is supposed to work with only one child. So to prevent any future bugs or problems put all your items in the `ScrollView` inside of another `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation.

## 1) Using LayoutTransition

This would only work from API Level 16 and above. Below API Level 16 visibility animations and translation animations would be handled automatically, but to get height changes animated you need to have API level 16.

One important thing I have to mention is that:

1. `LayoutTransition` animates changes for you. So you can remove all you custom animations if you use it. If you leave your own animations in you are just going to create conflicts with the animations performed by `LayoutTransition`.
2. If you don't like the animations performed by `LayoutTransition` you can customise them! I will explain how to do that further down below.

I usually use a helper method like this to setup a `LayoutTransition`.

```
public static void animateLayoutChanges(ViewGroup container) {
    final LayoutTransition transition = new LayoutTransition();
    transition.setDuration(300);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        transition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
        transition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.APPEARING);
        transition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGE_APPEARING);
        transition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING);
        transition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGE_DISAPPEARING);
    }

    container.setLayoutTransition(transition);
}
```

This will enable all possible automatic transitions on API Level 16 and above and just use the by default enabled transitions below that. Just use it like this:

```
AnimatorUtils.animateLayoutChanges(linearLayout);
```

If you call this method on the `LinearLayout` in your `ScrollView` then all changes to height/width/visibility of the `LinearLayout` and its direct children will be animated for you. Also item add/remove animations are taken care of for you.

To enable all kinds of transitions like resize animations you need to set the `LayoutTransitions` in code, but you can enable basic transitions like item add/remove animations by setting the property

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

on a `ViewGroup` in your xml layout.

There exists only minimal documentation on `LayoutTransitions`, but the basics are covered [**here**](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html).

If you want you can customise the animations for each event like adding/removing a `View` or changing something about the `View` like this:

```
// APPEARING handles items being added to the ViewGroup
transition.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.APPEARING, someAnimator);

// CHANGING handles among other things height or width changes of items in the ViewGroup
transition.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.CHANGING, someOtherAnimator);
```

Here is a DevByte video which explains `LayoutTransition`s in greater detail:

- [**LayoutTransitions enable easy fade/move/resize animations**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55wLsaWpQ4g)

<sub>Also note that container views can essentially cut off parts of the animations when the height of a parent changes. This won't happen in your case since your `ScrollView` has a fixed size and does not resize based on the children inside the `ScrollView`, but if you implement something like this in a `ViewGroup` with `wrap_content` then you need to set `android:clipChildren="false"` on all containers above the `View`s you are trying to animate. You can alternatively also use `setClipChildren()` in code.</sub>

---

## 2) Animating all items manually.

This is a much more difficult than using `LayoutTransition`s, mainly because you have to know a lot about the layouting and measuring process, otherwise you are going to cause problems. Nevertheless once you get the hang of it you can perform all kinds of custom animations.

The basic process is like this:

1. Record current `View` state.
2. Change layout to the state after the animations are finished
3. After Android is done layouting and measuring everything record the new values.
4. Now animate the `View`s from their old position to their new one

The core of this process is listening for changes in the view hierarchy. This is done using the `ViewTreeObserver`. There are multiple possible callbacks you can use, for example `OnPreDrawListener` or `OnGlobalLayoutListener`. Generally you would implement them like this:

```
final Animator animator = setupAnimator();
animator.setTarget(view);

// Record the current state
animator.setupStartValues();

modifyChildrenOfLinearLayout();

linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // Remove the callback immediately we only need to catch it this one time.
        linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

        // Record the new state
        animator.setupEndValues();

        // Start the animation
        animator.start();
    }
});
```

`OnGlobalLayoutListener` is better at catching layout changes since it is called after a layouting process has finished. `OnPreDrawListener` is called before the next frame is drawn, but their is no guarantee that the layouting process has already finished. But in practice this difference is negligible. Much more important is that on older slower devices there might be a short flash of the layout in its new state because they need some time to process each step. You can prevent that by using an `OnPreDrawListener` and returning `false` once. Since `OnGlobalLayoutListener` is also only completely available on newer API levels you should in most cases use `OnPreDrawListener`.

If `LayoutTransitions` does not provide you with an adequate solution to your problem and you have/want to implement the animations manually than learning how to perform animations efficiently is important. You can look at the source code of `LayoutTransition` [**here**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2_r1/android/animation/LayoutTransition.java#LayoutTransition.runChangeTransition%28android.view.ViewGroup%2Candroid.view.View%2Cint%29). The implementation of `LayoutTransition` essentially does exactly what I have been explaining here and it is a best practice implementation. I often find myself looking through the source code of the `android.animation` package to learn new things about how to animate efficiently and if you want to understand animations on Android I suggest you do the same!

You can also watch a few Android DevBytes videos about animations like this one:

- [**ListView Expanding Cells Animation**](https://m.youtube.com/?reload=2&rdm=1h1fw72nu#/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=mwE61B56pVQ)

In this video he explains how to animate an expanding cell in `ListView` by using an `OnPreDrawListener`.

---

Just always remember, the Layouting Engine is your friend. Don't try to reinvent the wheel and do stuff manually a layouting process would already do for you. And never call `requestLayout()` while performing animations!

Comment: Xaver, this answers my question and then some! Thank you for the very detailed answer! I'll be checking out all of the info you have provided. I really want to get to grips with the Android animation framework, I feel that it's one aspect of Android development in which my skills are still sorely lacking. Again, I can't thank you enough!

Comment: I have updated my answer a little! Glad I could help :)

Comment: Using the 'AnimatorUtils.animateLayoutChanges(linearLayout);' it makes my views to go over the action bar, then flicks back to where it should be, but irst of all it's not cool ! second is that it makes other fragments buggy too, ! have you got any thing to help me with, please?

Answer (score 0):

From Android Developer site : 
A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects. A child that is often used is a LinearLayout in a vertical orientation, presenting a vertical array of top-level items that the user can scroll through.

I can see that you have added multiple layouts as child in Scroll View, please add one linear layout and add rest of layout in that LinearLayout. 
Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this but unfortunately, it's still not working!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

      <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >


                <RelativeLayout >

                     </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout >

                     </LinearLayout>

      </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Scrollview must have only one child to it. So I created only one LinearLayout child and add your rest code in it.

Comment: I just tried it! Not working, unfortunately - the moved views still have content outside the viewport. It's really weird.

Comment: remove `android:fillViewport="true"` from scrollview and try. @Antonis427

Comment: Still nothing happening.

Comment: @Pooja translations through animations or anything like that have no effect on the layouting process, regardless of what you animate about the view the layouting engine will still see the view as of it was not animated at all. (unless you do something bad like constantly forcing a new layouting process while simultaneously changing `LayoutParams` or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

just add `android:clipChildren="false"`to your parent animated view and animation works outside of view.